# convert mysql timestamp into php user friendly version

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

i have 2011-08-03 21:56:41 coming from a MySQL timestamp and I would like to convert it to Wednesday August 3rd, 2011 using PHP (Not MySQL). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert your date/time string to a Unix timestamp so you can use [`date()`](http://php.net/date) to format the value of that timestamp any way you want.

```
$stamp = '2011-08-03 21:56:41';
echo date('l F jS, Y', strtotime($stamp));

// output: Wednesday August 3rd, 2011
```

The reference at the [`date()` manual page](http://php.net/date) is extremely useful. I still reference it all the time for the list of special format characters.

The `strtotime()` function sort of seems like magic at first. For future reference, [here's the supported date/time documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) on what input formats `strtotime()` can accept.